# IPN Simulator says accepted, but verification always comes back as "invalid"

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I have a script basically created from the few examples of a PayPal IPN calling I could find. When I run it through the simulator it says handshake was received and all's good. But based on the data sent back to me, the IPN is always coming back as invalid. Have no clude what is wrong and am in a tight space. Please help! Code below.

Listener page:

```
<?php
namespace Listener;

// Set this to true to use the sandbox endpoint during testing:
$enable_sandbox = true;
// Use this to specify all of the email addresses that you have attached to paypal:
$my_email_addresses = array("payment@mysite.com", "payment@mysite.com");
// Set this to true to send a confirmation email:
$send_confirmation_email = true;
$confirmation_email_address = "payment@mysite.com";
$from_email_address = "payment@mysite.com";
// Set this to true to save a log file:
$save_log_file = true;
$log_file_dir = __DIR__ . "/logs";
// Here is some information on how to configure sendmail:
// http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#118210
require('PaypalIPN.php');
use PaypalIPN;
$ipn = new PaypalIPN();
if ($enable_sandbox) {
    $ipn->useSandbox();
}
$verified = $ipn->verifyIPN();
$data_text = "";
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $data_text .= $key . " = " . $value . "\r\n";
}
$test_text = "";
if ($_POST["test_ipn"] == 1) {
    $test_text = "Test ";
}
// Check the receiver email to see if it matches your list of paypal email addresses
$receiver_email_found = false;
foreach ($my_email_addresses as $a) {
    if (strtolower($_POST["receiver_email"]) == strtolower($a)) {
        $receiver_email_found = true;
        break;
    }
}
date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
list($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second, $timezone) = explode(":", date("Y:m:d:H:i:s:T"));
$date = $year . "-" . $month . "-" . $day;
$timestamp = $date . " " . $hour . ":" . $minute . ":" . $second . " " . $timezone;
$dated_log_file_dir = $log_file_dir . "/" . $year . "/" . $month;
$paypal_ipn_status = "VERIFICATION FAILED";
if ($verified) {
    $paypal_ipn_status = "RECEIVER EMAIL MISMATCH";
    if ($receiver_email_found) {
        $paypal_ipn_status = "Completed Successfully";
        // Process IPN
        // A list of variables are available here:
        // https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/



    }
} elseif ($enable_sandbox) {
    if ($_POST["test_ipn"] != 1) {
        $paypal_ipn_status = "RECEIVED FROM LIVE WHILE SANDBOXED";
    }
} elseif ($_POST["test_ipn"] == 1) {
    $paypal_ipn_status = "RECEIVED FROM SANDBOX WHILE LIVE";
}
if ($save_log_file) {
    // Create log file directory
    if (!is_dir($dated_log_file_dir)) {
        if (!file_exists($dated_log_file_dir)) {
            mkdir($dated_log_file_dir, 0777, true);
            if (!is_dir($dated_log_file_dir)) {
                $save_log_file = false;
            }
        } else {
            $save_log_file = false;
        }
    }
    // Restrict web access to files in the log file directory
    $htaccess_body = "RewriteEngine On" . "\r\n" . "RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]";
    if ($save_log_file && (!is_file($log_file_dir . "/.htaccess") || file_get_contents($log_file_dir . "/.htaccess") !== $htaccess_body)) {
        if (!is_dir($log_file_dir . "/.htaccess")) {
            file_put_contents($log_file_dir . "/.htaccess", $htaccess_body);
            if (!is_file($log_file_dir . "/.htaccess") || file_get_contents($log_file_dir . "/.htaccess") !== $htaccess_body) {
                $save_log_file = false;
            }
        } else {
            $save_log_file = false;
        }
    }
    if ($save_log_file) {
        // Save data to text file
        file_put_contents($dated_log_file_dir . "/" . $test_text . "paypal_ipn_" . $date . ".txt", "paypal_ipn_status = " . $paypal_ipn_status . "\r\n" . "paypal_ipn_date = " . $timestamp . "\r\n" . $data_text . "\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
    }
}
if ($send_confirmation_email) {
    // Send confirmation email
    mail($confirmation_email_address, $test_text . "PayPal IPN : " . $paypal_ipn_status, "paypal_ipn_status = " . $paypal_ipn_status . "\r\n" . "paypal_ipn_date = " . $timestamp . "\r\n" . $data_text, "From: " . $from_email_address);
}
// Reply with an empty 200 response to indicate to paypal the IPN was received correctly
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");



?>
```

And the PayPalINP class:

```
<?php
class PaypalIPN
{
    /** @var bool Indicates if the sandbox endpoint is used. */
    private $use_sandbox = true;
    /** @var bool Indicates if the local certificates are used. */
    private $use_local_certs = false;
    /** Production Postback URL */
    const VERIFY_URI = 'https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    /** Sandbox Postback URL */
    const SANDBOX_VERIFY_URI = 'https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    /** Response from PayPal indicating validation was successful */
    const VALID = 'VERIFIED';
    /** Response from PayPal indicating validation failed */
    const INVALID = 'INVALID';
    /**
     * Sets the IPN verification to sandbox mode (for use when testing,
     * should not be enabled in production).
     * @return void
     */
    public function useSandbox()
    {
        $this->use_sandbox = true;
    }
    /**
     * Sets curl to use php curl's built in certs (may be required in some
     * environments).
     * @return void
     */
    public function usePHPCerts()
    {
        $this->use_local_certs = false;
    }
    /**
     * Determine endpoint to post the verification data to.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPaypalUri()
    {
        if ($this->use_sandbox) {
            return self::SANDBOX_VERIFY_URI;
        } else {
            return self::VERIFY_URI;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Verification Function
     * Sends the incoming post data back to PayPal using the cURL library.
     *
     * @return bool
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function verifyIPN()
    {
        if ( ! count($_POST)) {
            throw new Exception("Missing POST Data");
        }
        $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
        $myPost = array();
        foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
            $keyval = explode('=', $keyval);
            if (count($keyval) == 2) {
                // Since we do not want the plus in the datetime string to be encoded to a space, we manually encode it.
                /*if ($keyval[0] === 'payment_date') {
                    if (substr_count($keyval[1], '+') === 1) {
                        $keyval[1] = str_replace('+', '%2B', $keyval[1]);
                    }
                }*/
                $myPost[$keyval[0]] = $keyval[1];
            }
        }
        // Build the body of the verification post request, adding the _notify-validate command.
        $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
        $get_magic_quotes_exists = false;
        if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
            $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
        }
        foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
            if ($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
                $value = stripslashes($value);
            } else {
                $value = $value;
            }
            $req .= "&$key=$value";
        }
        // Post the data back to PayPal, using curl. Throw exceptions if errors occur.
        $ch = curl_init($this->getPaypalUri());
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        // This is often required if the server is missing a global cert bundle, or is using an outdated one.
        if ($this->use_local_certs) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, __DIR__ . "/cert/cacert.pem");
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'User-Agent: PHP-IPN-Verification-Script',
            'Connection: Close',
        ));
        $res = curl_exec($ch);
        if ( ! ($res)) {
            $errno = curl_errno($ch);
            $errstr = curl_error($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            throw new Exception("cURL error: [$errno] $errstr");
        }
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        $http_code = $info['http_code'];
        if ($http_code != 200) {
            throw new Exception("PayPal responded with http code $http_code");
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        // Check if PayPal verifies the IPN data, and if so, return true.
        if ($res == self::VALID) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want the plus in the date-time string to stay exactly as it is, not be encoded as a space or %2B.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but could you explain a little further? I am not understanding what you see wrong.

Comment: I am not understanding why you're doing it in the first place. The date-time string is the value part of a parameter. Spaces in parameters are encoded as '+'. Not themselves, and not %2B. The essence of IPN verification is that you send the parameters back exactly as you received them, and PayPal recomputes the hash and compares it with what it sent. If you mess around with them *in* ***any*** *way* this process cannot possibly work.

Comment: That makes perfect sense the way you explain it. Honestly, this was mostly copied and pasted from the github examples PayPal provides. Im a bit lost as you can tell. So which lines exactly should I remove? I have no clue why it is there in the first place. Thank you sooooo much.

Comment: Just remove the five lines after the comment. And don't call `urldecode()` or `urlencode()`. Just copy the parameters the way they are.

Comment: After the comment?.... l'm sorry man, which doc are you referring to? These lines?

date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
list($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second, $timezone) = explode(":", date("Y:m:d:H:i:s:T"));
$date = $year . "-" . $month . "-" . $day;
$timestamp = $date . " " . $hour . ":" . $minute . ":" . $second . " " . $timezone;
$dated_log_file_dir = $log_file_dir . "/" . $year . "/" . $month;

Comment: I also do not find urldecode() or urlencode() in my two docs...that's confusing me as well. Sorry and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Err, the comment about changing the plus in the date-time string? The unwanted stuff I' ve been talking about all this time? As for the decode/encode, look harder.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I was looking at the wrong file! Now, where the urlencode is used, should I simply comment-out those lines, or the whole foreach statement?     I have taken out the 5 lines of code below the comment "// Since we do not want the plus in the datetime string to be encoded to a space, we manually encode it." And also took out the three lines that use urlencode and urldecode....but it still is coming back invalid :( Why would PayPal have an example with busted code? So frustrating.

Comment: You should remove the calls and change them to assignments, e.g. `a = urlencode(b)` just becomes `a = b`.

Comment: It still does not work, and the date is gone from the IPN results. I have updated my code above to what I THINK you are saying. Could you please provide an answer with the code snippet? It may be simple to you, but none of their documentation is very helpful. Their support on integration is basically non-existent. Why would they provide an example that has such a major flaw. This makes no sense.

Comment: Just found this report of the same happening a week ago on the Github. https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/issues/135

Comment: I would get rid of *all* the futzing around with parameters, e.g. the magic-quotes thing, and just send the parameters exactly as you got them. I'm not aware whether PHP already decodes them for you, but if it does you will have to urlencode them after all. I have Java code that's been there for ten years with none of this futzing around with parameter values other than URL encoding, and hundreds of verified IPNs that prove it works.

Comment: Yeah, I hear you...mine has worked for 8 years, but I have to change it according to PayPal. Could you please post the section(s) of code you are talking about with suggested code? I feel like I am guessing. That would really give me a hand friend.

Comment: Am I allowed to offer a paypal donation for an answer on stackoverflow?

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you find a solution? Would you share it? :)